# Set publickeytoken on DLL in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, publickeytoken

i generated(with build project) a DLL file with a class library project in VS. Now I wanted to implement it in a program, but it sees no Publickeytoken in the DLL File. Do You know how I make this Token in VS?

Comment: Do you need one? Why? If you need it, set the strong name key in the properties window.

Comment: the public key token is part of the assembly manifest. it is generated only for strongly named (signed) assemblies.

Comment: I created one  strongly named key with the algorithm sha256RSA. But in the program (dynamics NAV) it does not show the token. And without that i cant use the functions from this DLL